# Definition of Divicibility

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I came up with this small doubt in basics while going through the Diophantine equation.

My question is if $d$ divides $a$ then does d divides $ax$ for all real numbers?

For the case where $x$ is an integer it is true but what aboutthe other. It seems like there is nothing wrong with it but if so then it will lead to some absurd results.

If I ask the question in a different way:
Do we consider $0.4 = 4*0.1$ as a number divicible by $4$ ?

Comment: Do you consider $\,\pi = 4 \cdot \cfrac{\pi}{4}\,$ as a number divisible by $\,4\,$?

Comment: $d\mid a\iff a=dk$ for some *integer* $k$.  If you were to relax this and allow $k$ to be any real number then you will find every nonzero real number then would "divide" every other nonzero real number.  Indeed, in the context of the field of real numbers, every number is either zero or is a unit.  Certainly, the notion of divisibility in the ring of integers is much more interesting than the notion of divisibility in the field of real numbers.

Comment: For a specific example, take $d=4$, $a=60$, and $x=1/20$.....

Comment: Thank you. So the ring should be clearly specified before defining the divicibility.

Answer (score 1):

Divisibility is with respect to a given ring . In the ring of integers 2|6 since 6=2*3 and since 6x=2*3x  2 also divides 6x for any INTEGER x.
 The Real numbers is not only a ring but a field (a non zero real x has and inverse x^-1 so 1=xx^-1 so x divides 1 so x divides any real number y .
 y=x(x^-1 y) . The concept of x divides y is therefore trivial and not usually referred to in this way .

Comment: Thank you. So it is the ring which matter s

Comment: Right ,you are welcome